# how to write unsigned short on a text file in java

Tags: java

I am using `DataOutOutputStream.writeShort();` method to write short on a text file, but using this method I can only write `-32768` to `32767`, but I don't want to write -ve short but there is no method like `writeUnsignedShort();` in `DataOutputStream`, is there any way to write `unsigned short` on a text file???

Comment: I presume it's writing in binary. Promote it to an `int`?

Answer (score 2):

> DataOutOutputStream.writeShort(); method to write short on a text file,

DataOutputStream is only for writing *binary*, if you want to write to a text file, you should use PrintWriter (or some other Writer)

> I don't want to write -ve short but there is no method like writeUnsignedShort(); in DataOutputStream, is there any way to write unsigned short on a text file

For binary files, there is only bytes, not -ve or +ve, The rest is in your imagination ;) If you want to write an unsigned short to a *binary* you can do this

```
int unsignedShort = 0 to 65535
dos.writeShort((short) unsignedShort);
```

and read it with

```
int unsignedShort = dos.readShort() & 0xFFFF;
```

To write an unsigned short to a *text* file this is exactly the same as writing an `int`

```
pw.print(unsignedShort);
```

You can read this with Scanner.nextInt()

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have Unsigned data types, except char, SO you can cast the int to char and use putChar() as follows:

```
myBuffer.putChar((char) my16BitInt);
```

Comment: using this I can only write up to 255 because ascii limit is 0 to 255, but i want to write as many +ve numbers as possible, so what should i do???

Comment: you can use as much as 65,535 numbers by using char rather than -32768 to 32767 in short int.

Answer (score 0):

What you're searching for is the `char` datatype. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
It's equivalent to the unsigned short you are searching for.

Comment: If you print a `char` to a text file you will get something very different to a number. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know that. I also know that `char` is the only unsigned data type on 16 bits in Java, which sucks in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to represent it as an integer with a mask of 0X0000FFFF